# How to speed up Mongodb text search, while searching for words that start with a sequence

Tags: mongodb

We have a website made with ReactJS (front-end), Python (back-end), and MongoDB as the database. We have a page where the user can search for words in text stored in the database. The search field is autocomplete; as the user types, he is shown suggestions of words contained in the database documents that begin with that sequence of characters. So for example if he types "act", he is shown suggestions such as "actor", "actress", "acting" (as long as those words exist in the documents in the database).
The problem is that as the database has got bigger, search has become considerably slower. The user has to wait 1-2 seconds for the suggestions to appear. We tried to speed the search by using a text index on the documents, so we can do the query like:

```
db.documents.find( { $text: { $search: "act" } } );
```

The problem is that since we are looking for documents that contain words that *begin* with "act", and not documents that contain the word "act", this doesn't work (it only fetches documents that contain "act", not documents containing only "acting"). I saw [here](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/full-text-search-partial-match/129874/4) that maybe the autocomplete operator could help us, but that is available only on MongoDB Atlas, which we don't have. Any ideas on how we could speed up the search?

**Edit:**
To answer the comment: The original query we are using is

```
db.documents.find({original_text: {$regex: search_string}})
```

I am trying to combine this with text index searching, as described [here](https://medium.com/statuscode/how-to-speed-up-mongodb-regex-queries-by-a-factor-of-up-to-10-73995435c606):

```
    db.documents.find({
     $and:[{
       $text: {
          $search: search_string_without_regexp
      }},{
       original_text: {$regex: search_string_with_regexp}
      }]
);
```

(I have created a plain_text field that contains the plain text version of original_text, and that is the field that has the index). The search string in any case will contain just one word (if the user inputs more than one word, we only search for the first one)

**Edit 2**
The execution plan:

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "aristotelistes_db_prod.documents",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "original_text" : {
                "$regex" : "(\\W|\\b|$)δ[()†F\\[\\]]*(- ?(&&[0-9a-zα-ω\\.]+&&)*(\n)+(\\$(\\w|\\.)+\\$)? ?{[0-9α-ωa-z]+}\t* ?)?[()†F\\[\\]]*[υὐὑὒὓὔὕὖὗὺύῦῢΰῧῠῡύ][()†F\\[\\]]*(- ?(&&[0-9a-zα-ω\\.]+&&)*(\n)+(\\$(\\w|\\.)+\\$)? ?{[0-9α-ωa-z]+}\t* ?)?[()†F\\[\\]]*ν"
            }
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
            "filter" : {
                "original_text" : {
                    "$regex" : "(\\W|\\b|$)δ[()†F\\[\\]]*(- ?(&&[0-9a-zα-ω\\.]+&&)*(\n)+(\\$(\\w|\\.)+\\$)? ?{[0-9α-ωa-z]+}\t* ?)?[()†F\\[\\]]*[υὐὑὒὓὔὕὖὗὺύῦῢΰῧῠῡύ][()†F\\[\\]]*(- ?(&&[0-9a-zα-ω\\.]+&&)*(\n)+(\\$(\\w|\\.)+\\$)? ?{[0-9α-ωa-z]+}\t* ?)?[()†F\\[\\]]*ν"
                }
            },
            "direction" : "forward"
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : []
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 1364,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 812,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 0,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 2676,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
            "filter" : {
                "original_text" : {
                    "$regex" : "(\\W|\\b|$)δ[()†F\\[\\]]*(- ?(&&[0-9a-zα-ω\\.]+&&)*(\n)+(\\$(\\w|\\.)+\\$)? ?{[0-9α-ωa-z]+}\t* ?)?[()†F\\[\\]]*[υὐὑὒὓὔὕὖὗὺύῦῢΰῧῠῡύ][()†F\\[\\]]*(- ?(&&[0-9a-zα-ω\\.]+&&)*(\n)+(\\$(\\w|\\.)+\\$)? ?{[0-9α-ωa-z]+}\t* ?)?[()†F\\[\\]]*ν"
                }
            },
            "nReturned" : 1364,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 802,
            "works" : 2678,
            "advanced" : 1364,
            "needTime" : 1313,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 44,
            "restoreState" : 44,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "direction" : "forward",
            "docsExamined" : 2676
        },
        "allPlansExecution" : []
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "aristotelistes",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "4.4.3",
        "gitVersion" : "913d6b62acfbb344dde1b116f4161360acd8fd13"
    },
    "ok" : 1.0,
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1684327662, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : { "$binary" : "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=", "$type" : "00" },
            "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    },
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1684327662, 1)
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown us the query that you are currently using or it's `.explain("allPlansExecution")` output. In any case, I don't think MongoDB is natively well-suited for what you are trying to do unless, as you point out, you use their Search functionality in Atlas. Without it you may need to manually tokenize and store the information in the documents. How many fields are you searching and how many words are in the strings?

Comment: I have updated the original question with more info